# Typescript Function Parameter as Union of Set<T> and Array<T>

Tags: typescript, union-types

I'm trying to use a union type of Set and Array as function parameter:

```
export function demo(
  items: Set<string> | string[]
): Set<string> {
  const allItems = new Set<string>();
  items.forEach((item: string) => {
    allItems.add(item);
  });
  return allItems;
}
```

However, the code does not compile. It throws the following error message:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. 
Type '((callbackfn: (value: string, value2: string, set: Set<string>) => void, thisArg?: any) => void) | ((callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => void, thisArg?: any) => void)' has no compatible call signatures.
```

I understand that Set and Array have different methods, but both have the forEach() method, which is the only one I'm using.

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using?  Support for call signatures of union types was [improved](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) in TS3.3 so it should [work](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwCbAC2EAFAFBxyYxEDOAXHAMrAwA8tMUmKA5gHxwAPnE7c+AbQC6ZAJSMW7MTwFwA3hThocnOAEMANgYCSNQrTgBeOCmAB3Zqw5cV-ErIDcm6nQB0CaABRPTQACxISH0JGZT5ZK0ENSkpDEzNaXz08PEizT00AX3zKKFYkKFxU0zovAqA) with no error

Comment: Ok, I'm still on 3.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use only forEach, you can just define a type like this:

```js
type WithForEach<T> = { 
   forEach: (callbackfn: (value: T) => void) => void; 
};

export const demo = (
    items: WithForEach<string>
): Set<string> => {
    const allItems = new Set<string>();
    items.forEach((item: string) => {
        allItems.add(item);
    });
    return allItems;
};
```

It should be compatible with the `Set` and `Array` types.